# I get an error when clicking the buttons repeatedly. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a question and answer application. I take the questions from the arraylist. but when moving on to the next question my application gets an error. There is an animation when moving to the next question in my application, and during this animation, the buttons of the previous question get an error when clicked again while moving. My guess is that when clicked again, he wants to check whether the previous question is true or false, but he cannot find the previous question because the code goes to the next question. but I couldn't find how to fix it. my mistake is attached below

logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)' on a null object reference
        at com.haktansoft.tytayt.islamidevir.checkAns(islamidevir.java:427)
        at com.haktansoft.tytayt.islamidevir.access$000(islamidevir.java:41)
        at com.haktansoft.tytayt.islamidevir$1.onClick(islamidevir.java:264)
```

Here is the line of errors I get in Logcat

```
java:427  =  correctOption.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#14E39A")));
java:41   =  public class islamidevir extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
java:264  =  checkAns((Button) v);
```

java code :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                linearLayout1.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        checkAns((Button) v);
    
                    }
                });
    
            }
            Random randomizer = new Random();
    
            sira  = (randomizer.nextInt(list.size()));
    txtnumberIndicator.setText(position + 1 + "/" + list.size());
    playAnim(txtQuestions, 0, list.get(sira).getQuestions());
            Next_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Next_btn.setEnabled(false);
                    Next_btn.setAlpha(0.7f);
                    enableOptions(true);
                    position++;
                    sira  = (randomizer.nextInt(list.size()));
    
            }
            });
    
            navigationDrawer();
        }

private void checkAns(Button selectedOptions) {
        enableOptions(false);
        Next_btn.setEnabled(true);
        Next_btn.setAlpha(1);
        if (selectedOptions.getText().toString().equals(list.get(sira).getCorrectAnswer())) {
            //correct Answer
            score++;
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ding);
            selectedOptions.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#14E39A")));
            mp.start();
        } else {
            //wrong Answer
            final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wrong_buzzer);
            selectedOptions.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF2B55")));
            Button correctOption = linearLayout1.findViewWithTag(list.get(sira).getCorrectAnswer());
            correctOption.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#14E39A")));
            mp.start();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you click multiple times you are moving to the next context, so the actual which is becoming the previous button doesn't exist anymore.

I think you can add a verification inside your method checkAns(p pParamater) something like this :

```
checkAns(P pParameter) {
     if(pParameter.notNullOrEmpty() {
          then ...
     }
}
```

Or having a state : isMoving and check on this state.

Comment: I think you can do a button.setEnabled(true) and with this method you are sure that you can't click multiple times until you have your new button.